# How to inject Symfony 6 workflow with API Platform 3

Tags: api, symfony, collections, workflow, platform

I am trying to inject information about my workflow into my entity data using API Platform and using a collection.

I have created a ProviderInterface, but I am not sure how to use it properly.
Here's my attempt at writing the code:

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
final class ItemsProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    private $workflowRegistry;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Registry $workflowRegistry)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->workflowRegistry = $workflowRegistry;
    }

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        $isCollectionOperation = $operation instanceof GetCollection;
        dump($operation);

        if ($isCollectionOperation) {
            // What I do here ??
            $entites = [new Items(), new Items()];
        } else {
            $entite = new Items($uriVariables['id']);
        }

        $entites = $isCollectionOperation ? $entites : [$entite];

        foreach ($entites as $entite) {
            dump($entite);
            $workflow = $this->workflowRegistry->get($entite, $entite->getForm()->getWorkflow());

            $entite->setWorkflowName($workflow->getName());
        }

        return $isCollectionOperation ? $entites : $entites[0];
    }
}
```

My api platform declaration:

```
#[ApiResource(
    provider: ItemsProvider::class,
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(),
        new Get(security: "is_granted('ITEMS_READ', object)"),
    ],
    routePrefix: '/moqy',
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['items:list', 'user:list', 'rh:list']],
    paginationEnabled: true,
    paginationItemsPerPage: 100,
    security: "is_granted('ROLE_MOQY_USER')",
    order: ['id' => 'DESC']
)]
```

And the URL for the collection is: /moqy/items

Comment: Old post, but I don't understand what you wanted to do. Workflows are useful to update a status of an entity, as example. So, the workflow should be used when you're using a "patch" request. And IMO, the best way to use a workflow is with [core controllers](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/).